# Como fazer para transformar a largura de uma div 'infinita'?

Tags: html, css

Estou criando uma aplicação com várias colunas, cada coluna com várias etiquetas. Na tela cabem aproximadamente 5 colunas, no máximo, após isso elas recomeçam uma embaixo das outras, assim.

```
COLUNA1 COLUNA2 COLUNA3 COLUNA4 COLUNA5
COLUNA6 COLUNA7 COLUNA8 COLUNA9 COLUNA10
COLUNA11 ...
```

Eu gostaria que isso não ocorresse, mas que elas continuassem sempre para a direita, independente de quantas eu insira, assim.

```
COLUNA1 COLUNA2 COLUNA3 COLUNA4 COLUNA5 COLUNA6 COLUNA7 COLUNA8 ...
```

E também inserir uma barra de rolagem vertical para ver todas as colunas.
Da mesma forma, preciso que em cada coluna eu insira quantas etiquetas eu quiser, e a altura da coluna (com um tamanho mínimo) aumente conforme o número de etiquetas.

Meu código está assim.

```css
.coluna1 {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 280px;
    height: 600px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    float: left;
}

.oportunidade1 {
    padding: 10px;
    color: black;
    background: rgba(69, 164, 255, 0.45);
    border: 1px solid #828282;
}
```

```html
<section class="content">

    <div class="colunas-status">
        <div class="coluna1">
            <div class="oportunidade1">
                <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                <p>ID: 4 - R$ 700,00</p>
                <p>Rafael MZ</p>
            </div>
            <div class="oportunidade1">
                <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                <p>ID: 4 - R$ 700,00</p>
                <p>Rafael MZ</p>
            </div>
            <div class="oportunidade1">
                <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                <p>ID: 4 - R$ 700,00</p>
                <p>Rafael MZ</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="coluna1">
            <div class="oportunidade1">
                <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                <p>ID: 4 - R$ 700,00</p>
                <p>Rafael MZ</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="coluna1">
            <div class="oportunidade1">
                <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                <p>ID: 4 - R$ 700,00</p>
                <p>Rafael MZ</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="coluna1">
            <div class="oportunidade1">
                <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                <p>ID: 4 - R$ 700,00</p>
                <p>Rafael MZ</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara uma das formas de fazer é com `display:flex` e `overflow-x:auto`, ai as colunas vão ir ficando "infinitamente" uma ao lado da outra sem quebrar a linha.

**OBS:** Não mexi em nada no seu HTML, não precisei colocar classe nos elementos, pois vc já havia colocando, então só precisei fazer uns ajustes como falei no CSS e colocar flex na classe `.colunas-status`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Execute em Página toda** para visualizar melhor, o `snippet` aqui do site tem pouca altura e fica ruim de testar.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.coluna1 {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  float: left;
}

.oportunidade1 {
  padding: 10px;
  color: black;
  background: rgba(69, 164, 255, 0.45);
  border: 1px solid #828282;

  width: 280px;
}

.colunas-status {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="content">

    <div class="colunas-status">
        <div class="coluna1">
            <div class="oportunidade1">
                <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                <p>ID: 4 - R$ 700,00</p>
                <p>Rafael MZ</p>
            </div>
            <div class="oportunidade1">
                <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                <p>ID: 4 - R$ 700,00</p>
                <p>Rafael MZ</p>
            </div>
            <div class="oportunidade1">
                <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                <p>ID: 4 - R$ 700,00</p>
                <p>Rafael MZ</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="coluna1">
            <div class="oportunidade1">
                <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                <p>ID: 4 - R$ 700,00</p>
                <p>Rafael MZ</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="coluna1">
            <div class="oportunidade1">
                <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                <p>ID: 4 - R$ 700,00</p>
                <p>Rafael MZ</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="coluna1">
            <div class="oportunidade1">
                <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                <p>ID: 4 - R$ 700,00</p>
                <p>Rafael MZ</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="coluna1">
            <div class="oportunidade1">
                <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                <p>ID: 4 - R$ 700,00</p>
                <p>Rafael MZ</p>
            </div>
            <div class="oportunidade1">
                <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                <p>ID: 4 - R$ 700,00</p>
                <p>Rafael MZ</p>
            </div>
            <div class="oportunidade1">
                <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                <p>ID: 4 - R$ 700,00</p>
                <p>Rafael MZ</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="coluna1">
            <div class="oportunidade1">
                <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                <p>ID: 4 - R$ 700,00</p>
                <p>Rafael MZ</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="coluna1">
            <div class="oportunidade1">
                <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                <p>ID: 4 - R$ 700,00</p>
                <p>Rafael MZ</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="coluna1">
            <div class="oportunidade1">
                <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                <p>ID: 4 - R$ 700,00</p>
                <p>Rafael MZ</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</section>
```